# How to get and handle form changes in a different form that is accessible from Application.OpenForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm currently using a delegate to poll the current active control from the currently focused external form every few milliseconds, which works badly.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why do you need to know this information?

Comment: I'm working on a automated testing component. The goal is to write to an external file whenever the "external" form's focus or control changes. Unfortunately, I only have access the testing component's code base and not the other forms that I'm trying to get info from.

Answer (score 0):

The title of the question is somewhat confusing, as this does not actually have anything to do with `Application.OpenForms`. That property just exposes a collection of all the currently open forms. If a new form is opened that had not previously been opened, it will be added to the collection. But the operating system allows only one active window at a time on the desktop, so what you really want is to get notified when the active window changes. Polling will work for this, but it isn't a good solution.

You will either need to install [a global hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959.aspx) (WH_CBT is likely the one you want), or take advantage of the [WinEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373889.aspx) infrastructure (via the [SetWinEventHook function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640.aspx)) intended for accessibility tools. Both of these will provide you with a notification when the active window changes. Of course, their scope won't be limited to the application that you are testing. You'll get notification when the active window on the desktop changes to any other window. It will be up to you to filter that down to the application you care about.

I don't have time at the moment to translate any of the required code to C#/.NET, but you can probably find it somewhere online, once you know what to search for. Additionally, WinEvents is already wrapped for you in the [`System.Windows.Automation` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.aspx).